# Easy Method to Encrypt a 500GB portable USB drive with True Crypt?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I have a 500GB portable USB drive with about 111GB free space.  I followed the steps to make a container on the drive and set the container size to 500GB.  I selected AES+Twofish+Serpent for the encryption and NTFS as the format.  When I click the format button it starts to format but indicates the process will take 26+hours.

Is there a faster/easier way to do this?  Or is the wait time just a consequence of creating such a large file?

Answer (score 1):

USB connected drives are slower, and the encryption selected does also slow things down.

If there's a scheduled defrag or antivirus, those processes will also delay the process; you may wish to disable those pro tem, especially if your laptop CPU is single core.

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/troubleshooting  has more specific information.

Answer (score 1):

You are encrypting a 500GB file stored on the USB-connected device. You can just tune the things up when you give this encryption process the highest priority:

```
renice -n -20 -p 1234
```

where `1234` is the pid of the running process and `-20` is the highest priority.